# Jetty webSocket | How to monitor time latency

Tags: java, jetty

I've a time critical webSocket app which uses Jetty 10.0.7 and expose metric through JMX. In my app I want to find latency of outbound msg which includes queue wait time and network latency. I tried to search jetty metric but i can't seems to found any latency related metric.

Any idea if there any metric exists or any work around way to find it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Currently the only WebSocket statistics available through Jetty are by using the `ConnectionStatistics` mechanism. You can use the `IncludeExcludeConnectionStatistics` class and configure it to only record stats for `WebSocketConnection.class` to only record statistics for WebSocket. Otherwise if you use standard `ConnectionStatistics` it will combine both HTTP and WebSocket statistics.

You can see the different stats you can get from this in the javadoc:
https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/javadoc/jetty-10/org/eclipse/jetty/io/ConnectionStatistics.html

It doesn't provide statistic you're looking for. So the best thing to do is to implement this in your WebSocket endpoint. You could use ping/pong frames to measure round-trip time, you could use the `WriteCallback` to measure time it takes to send a message etc...